# Increase power delivery during Android USB Debugging

Tags: usb, power-supply, android

I use Android USB debugging to debug my own app. The app has high power requirements since it stresses the camera bus a lot. The power consumtion is so high that the phone's battery discharges during USB debugging and the phone turns off at some point. When I run the app without USB debugging and use the regular wall charger (2 Ampere) the battery does not discharge and stays at 100%. This leads to the conculsion that my mainboard can not deliver enough power to the phone. Is there any way to increase it?

What I've tryed so far:

- Using a cheap USB hub with an external power supply, it hat no effect at all
- Checked all BIOS settings related to USB power delivery, they had no effect either
- Tried different USB ports

Is there maybe a special Cable that uses Power delivery from Source A and the datalines from Source B?

Please Note:

- The App has to use that much power! Reducing the power consumtion isn't possible without loosing performance. (Display is already at minimum brightness and Wifi etc. are turned off)
- The phone needs to be connected via USB to the Computer to transfer data. So debugging over Wi-Fi etc. are no options either
- The phone uses USB 2.0 with a micro USB connector

Comment: Your Mainboard and device are simply working USB compliant. USB 2.0 devices are allowed to draw a maximum of 0.5 A. For more power you need an USB 3 device (0.9 A) or even better one that supports USB-PD.

Comment: @Robert Yes. Yet I would consider the offical wall charger USB compliant aswell and it can deliver up to 2 Amps. This is why I am asking if there is maybe a way using a special cable or USB hub.

Comment: Is don't thing the wall charger will help you as usually devices detect that they are connected to a charger by the not connected data cables. Only then the 0.5A restriction is ignored. So you can't have both, USB data connection and increased current at the same time.

Comment: If this is true then there is no solution to my problem, right? And what about the "USB Y Cables" that are beeing sold. Are those just snake oil?

Comment: The Y cables are in general a violation of the USB standard. They only work for devices which themself ignore the USB standard and draw more than the allowed 0.5A for USB 2 or 0.9A for USB 3. The idea behind the Y cables is to avoid destroying USB ports by drawing too much power from it (or to improve the maximum current that is available to the USB device).

Comment: So couldn't it be possible that my phone is a "device which ignores the USB standard and draws more than the allowed 0.5A for USB 2"?

Comment: If it would ignore the standard then you would not have a problem. Especially in combination with the self-powered USB hub would have solved your problem if it would ignore the USB standard.